# Apply Twitter Bootstrap stylings to CodeMirror?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, code-editor

I have a form with a textarea where users can write some code. I'm replacing that textarea with a [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) code editor box, so I want to apply Bootstrap stylings to it.

This is what the form looks like right now, where all the form elements except the code editor have Bootstrap stylings: [image]

So in particular, I think I need to give the code editor rounded corners, a border, the correct width (input-xxlarge), and blue highlights when mousing over.

How do I do this? Is there a way of doing this besides manually copying over the necessary CSS?

## UPDATE

I tried copying over the textarea CSS from Bootstrap, and all looks good except the focus CSS when I click inside the code editor. This is what I get:

[image]

The highlight is on the inside, instead of the outside. Any ideas how I fix this?

This is the CSS I added by copying from Bootstrap:

```
    .CodeMirror {
      line-height: 1.3em;
      font-family: monospace;

      /* Necessary so the scrollbar can be absolutely positioned within the wrapper on Lion. */
      position: relative;
      /* This prevents unwanted scrollbars from showing up on the body and wrapper in IE. */
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: white;
      width: 530px;

      /* Copied from Bootstrap's textarea */
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 4px 6px;
      margin-bottom: 9px;
      color: #555555;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
      -moz-border-radius: 3px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
      -webkit-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
      -moz-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
      -ms-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
      -o-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
      transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;  
    }

    .CodeMirror-focused {
      /* Copied from Bootstrap's textarea */
      border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
      outline: 0;
      outline: thin dotted \9;
      /* IE6-9 */

      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
         -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
              box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);  
    }
```

Comment: Copied your code and it seems to work for me without any changes, or perhaps you fixed it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CodeMirror hides the original `textarea` and creates a (fairly complex) structure of `div` and `pre` elements. You can style the outermost `div` which has a class of `.CodeMirror` to achieve the same effect.

This will require customizing the CodeMirror stylesheet or adding your own style for the class/element. If you are building Bootstrap using LESS, there may be a way to apply a mixin to avoid duplicating the `textarea` style, though the amount of duplication is probably minimal.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I tried copying over the CSS from Bootstrap's textarea, and it looks mostly correct, except when I focus on the code editor. (I updated my question above.) The blue highlights are internal to the code editor, instead of surrounding it. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: The outline might behave differently because the element types are different. I'll set up a quick JS Fiddle and see if that's the case.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YhLjn/ - it looks like the outline behaves the same on a `div` and `textarea`. Perhaps the `focused` class is being applied to an inner element?

Answer (score 11):

**Code Mirror and Bootstrap (v3 and v4):**
Styling does not yet support validation states (has-error, has-warning, has-success)

```css
.CodeMirror {
  /* Bootstrap Settings */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  font: inherit;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: inherit;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075); /* Bootstrap 3 */
  box-shadow: none; /* Bootstrap 4 */
  transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
  /* Code Mirror Settings */
  font-family: monospace;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
    
.CodeMirror-focused {
  /* Bootstrap Settings */
  border-color: #66afe9;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, .6); /* Bootstrap 3 */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 .2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, .25); /* Bootstrap 4 */
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
```

Comment: 2019 and this still works like a charm in Bootstrap 4!

Comment: And in 2020 with Bootstrap 4! I only needed to change `padding: 6px 12px;` to `padding: 6px 6px;` to make it look right. Thanks!

Comment: @ZackTarr - Appreciate the affirmation, but I think the `box-shadow` for Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 4 are different. See the updated code.

Comment: @JosephVictorZammit - Appreciate the affirmation, but I think the `box-shadow` for Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 4 are different. See the updated code.